# Unique formula that excludes cells containing a specific word?

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, unique

How do I pull a Unique list that excludes cells containing a specific word?  I am trying to pull a list of categories from A24:A124 but I want it to exclude the "total" lines.  After each section, for example, for the "Beer" category, there is a line in column A after all the beer that says "Beer Total".  I do not want those "total" lines to be included in the unique list that I am pulling.

I tried using the below code but it still isn't removing cells that contain the word "Total".  What am I missing here?

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A24:A124,A24:A124 <> " ",A24:A124 <>"*Total*"))
```

I've been playing around in cell F7 but it will eventually go in A6

Comment: I'm in Google Sheets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `REGEXMATCH`:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A24:A124,NOT(REGEXMATCH(A24:A124,"Total"))))
```

[image]

Comment: This is PERFECT and does exactly what I need it to do!!  Thank you!